# XACRO Macro Noetic not working

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm facing issues with xacro macros in ROS noetic. I have the following robot description (or a simplified version) containing one xacro macro. After the definition of the macro it is called by `<robot_macro/>`

Normally i have this macro defined in an other file and include it in a main xacro file, where i include a lot of macros and then build up the robot using those macros.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="robot1" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <xacro:macro name="robot_macro">
        <link name="robot1_base_link"/>
        <link name="beam_link">
            <inertial>
                <origin xyz="0.40 0 0.02" rpy="0 0 0" />
                <mass value="2" />
                <inertia ixx="0.003" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.09" iyz="0" izz="0.09" />
            </inertial>
            <visual>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
                </geometry>
                <material name="white">
                    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
                </material>
            </visual>
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0.4 0 0.02" rpy="0 0 0" />
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
                </geometry>
            </collision>
        </link>
        <joint name="beam_joint" type="fixed">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <parent link="robot1_base_link" />
            <child link="beam_link" />
            <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
        </joint>
    </xacro:macro>
    <robot_macro/>
</robot>
```

If i load the robot description in Gazebo, i get the error message `No link elements found in urdf.` At first i thought it could be that the mesh files can not be found. So i decided to switch to a simple conversion from xacro to urdf for debugging my problem. But if i convert this xacro file to a urdf file using `rosrun xacro xacro -o model.urdf model.xacro` the resulting urdf contains no links and joint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from mira3d.xacro                   | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="robot1">
  <robot_macro/>
</robot>
```

If i remove the two xacro macro lines around the links and joint (and the call of the macro), its working as expected. I am pretty sure, i used the xacro description like it is in Kinetic and Melodic before and had no problems with it. I also think the macro looks like the example on http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File

Can you see any issue with it or is there any change in xacro macros in noetic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372407/xacro-macro-noetic-not-working/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2021-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> <robot [..]>
> ```

```
    [..]
    <robot_macro/>
</robot>
```

I don't believe this is supposed to work like this.

Shouldn't it be at least:

```
<robot [..]>
    [..]
    <xacro:robot_macro/>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Erickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/39442/brian-erickson/) on 2021-03-01**:
This must have changed in Noetic.  In Melodic, I had macros that worked without the xacro namespace, but I needed to add them when I went to Noetic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-01**:
Actually, this has been deprecated since at least Jade. See [wiki/xacro - Deprecated Syntax](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Deprecated_Syntax).

And [ros/xacro#79](https://github.com/ros/xacro/pull/79). That's from 2015.